# How can I have multiple load and save Buttons with local storage?

Tags: javascript

I want to have multiple load and save buttons, for a program that generates outfits based on keywords. The problem I'm having with my code is that when I click any of the buttons, I check storage and topC BottomC ShoesC and Shoes2C contain all the text inputs i inserted, Even though I clicked Save 1 or Save 2. Same with loading, It only loads those 4 keys. Why is this happening? There's a lot of code so I doubt people would read it all, but thank you if you do.

```
function addStorage() {
    console.log("Add storage");
        //localStorage setItem
            if ("localStorage" in window) {
            console.log('Setting item ' + shoesimg.src +  'to shoesA in localStorage');
            localStorage.setItem('shoesA', shoesimg.src)
        }  
            if ("localStorage" in window) {
            console.log('Setting item ' + shoesimg2.src +  'to shoes2A in localStorage');
            localStorage.setItem('shoes2A', shoesimg2.src)
        }
            if ("localStorage" in window) {
            console.log('Setting item ' + topimg.src +  'to topA in localStorage');
            localStorage.setItem('topA', topimg.src)
        }
            if ("localStorage" in window) {
            console.log('Setting item ' + bottomimg.src +  'to bottomA in localStorage');
            localStorage.setItem('bottomA', bottomimg.src)
        }
        if(topinput.value != '' || bottominput.value != '' || shoesinput.value != ''){
        saveoutfit1.value = 'Saved!'
        saveoutfit1.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 167, 0)';
        setTimeout (function(){
        saveoutfit1.value = 'Save Outfit 1'
        saveoutfit1.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(119, 119, 223)';
        console.log('success')
        }, 2000);
    }
    if(topimg.src == '' || bottomimg.src == '' || shoesimg.src == ''){
        error.innerHTML += '<li>No Outfit Loaded</li>'
        setTimeout(function(){error.innerHTML = ''}, 2000)};
}
saveoutfit2.addEventListener('click', addStorage)
function addStorage() {
    console.log("Add storage");
        //localStorage setItem
            if ("localStorage" in window) {
            console.log('Setting item ' + shoesimg.src +  'to shoesB in localStorage');
            localStorage.setItem('shoesB', shoesimg.src)
        }  
            if ("localStorage" in window) {
            console.log('Setting item ' + shoesimg2.src +  'to shoes2B in localStorage');
            localStorage.setItem('shoes2B', shoesimg2.src)
        }
            if ("localStorage" in window) {
            console.log('Setting item ' + topimg.src +  'to topB in localStorage');
            localStorage.setItem('topB', topimg.src)
        }
            if ("localStorage" in window) {
            console.log('Setting item ' + bottomimg.src +  'to bottomB in localStorage');
            localStorage.setItem('bottomB', bottomimg.src)
        }
        if(topinput.value != '' || bottominput.value != '' || shoesinput.value != ''){
        saveoutfit2.value = 'Saved!'
        saveoutfit2.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 167, 0)';
        setTimeout (function(){
        saveoutfit2.value = 'Save Outfit 2'
        saveoutfit2.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(119, 119, 223)';
        console.log('success')
        }, 2000);
    }
    if(topimg.src == '' || bottomimg.src == '' || shoesimg.src == ''){
        error.innerHTML += '<li>No Outfit Loaded</li>'
        setTimeout(function(){error.innerHTML = ''}, 2000)};
    }
saveoutfit3.addEventListener('click', addStorage)
function addStorage() {
    console.log("Add storage");
        //localStorage setItem
            if ("localStorage" in window) {
            console.log('Setting item ' + shoesimg.src +  'to shoesC in localStorage');
            localStorage.setItem('shoesC', shoesimg.src)
        }  
            if ("localStorage" in window) {
            console.log('Setting item ' + shoesimg2.src +  'to shoes2C in localStorage');
            localStorage.setItem('shoes2C', shoesimg2.src)
        }
            if ("localStorage" in window) {
            console.log('Setting item ' + topimg.src +  'to topC in localStorage');
            localStorage.setItem('topC', topimg.src)
        }
            if ("localStorage" in window) {
            console.log('Setting item ' + bottomimg.src +  'to bottomC in localStorage');
            localStorage.setItem('bottomC', bottomimg.src)
        }
        if(topinput.value != '' || bottominput.value != '' || shoesinput.value != ''){
        saveoutfit3.value = 'Saved!'
        saveoutfit3.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 167, 0)';
        setTimeout (function(){
        saveoutfit3.value = 'Save Outfit 3'
        saveoutfit3.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(119, 119, 223)';
        console.log('success')
        }, 2000);
    }
    if(topimg.src == '' || bottomimg.src == '' || shoesimg.src == ''){
        error.innerHTML += '<li>No Outfit Loaded</li>'
        setTimeout(function(){error.innerHTML = ''}, 2000)};
}
    

//load storage
loadoutfit1.addEventListener('click', loadStorage)

function loadStorage(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('shoesA' || 'topA' || 'bottomA')!= ''){

   
        shoesimg.src = localStorage.getItem('shoesA');
        shoescontainer.appendChild(shoesimg);
        shoesimg.style.width = '100px';
        shoesimg.style.transform = 'scaleX(-1)';
        shoesimg2.src = localStorage.getItem('shoes2A');
        shoescontainer2.appendChild(shoesimg2);
        shoesimg2.style.width = '100px';
        topimg.src = localStorage.getItem('topA');
        topcontainer.appendChild(topimg);
        topimg.style.width = '200px';
        bottomimg.src = localStorage.getItem('bottomA');
        bottomcontainer.appendChild(bottomimg);
        bottomimg.style.width = '300px';
        faceimg.src = 'face.png';
        facecontainer.appendChild(faceimg);
        faceimg.style.width = '130px'
        
        loadoutfit1.value = 'Loaded!'
        loadoutfit1.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 167, 0)';
        setTimeout (function(){
        loadoutfit1.value = 'Load Outfit 1'
        loadoutfit1.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(119, 119, 223)';
        }, 2000);
    
    
    console.log('success');
    }
    if(localStorage.getItem('shoesA' || 'topA' || 'bottomA')== ''){
        error.innerHTML += '<li>No Outfit Saved</li>'
        setTimeout(function(){error.innerHTML = ''}, 2000)};
    }
    
loadoutfit2.addEventListener('click', loadStorage)

function loadStorage(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('shoesB' || 'topB' || 'bottomB')!= ''){

   
        shoesimg.src = localStorage.getItem('shoesB');
        shoescontainer.appendChild(shoesimg);
        shoesimg.style.width = '100px';
        shoesimg.style.transform = 'scaleX(-1)';
        shoesimg2.src = localStorage.getItem('shoes2B');
        shoescontainer2.appendChild(shoesimg2);
        shoesimg2.style.width = '100px';
        topimg.src = localStorage.getItem('topB');
        topcontainer.appendChild(topimg);
        topimg.style.width = '200px';
        bottomimg.src = localStorage.getItem('bottomB');
        bottomcontainer.appendChild(bottomimg);
        bottomimg.style.width = '300px';
        faceimg.src = 'face.png';
        facecontainer.appendChild(faceimg);
        faceimg.style.width = '130px'
        
        loadoutfit2.value = 'Loaded!'
        loadoutfit2.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 167, 0)';
        setTimeout (function(){
        loadoutfit2.value = 'Load Outfit 2'
        loadoutfit2.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(119, 119, 223)';
        }, 2000);
    
    
    console.log('success');
    }
    if(localStorage.getItem('shoesB' || 'topB' || 'bottomB')== ''){
        error.innerHTML += '<li>No Outfit Saved</li>'
        setTimeout(function(){error.innerHTML = ''}, 2000)};
    }

loadoutfit3.addEventListener('click', loadStorage)

function loadStorage(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('shoesC' || 'topC' || 'bottomC')!= ''){

   
        shoesimg.src = localStorage.getItem('shoesC');
        shoescontainer.appendChild(shoesimg);
        shoesimg.style.width = '100px';
        shoesimg.style.transform = 'scaleX(-1)';
        shoesimg2.src = localStorage.getItem('shoes2C');
        shoescontainer2.appendChild(shoesimg2);
        shoesimg2.style.width = '100px';
        topimg.src = localStorage.getItem('topC');
        topcontainer.appendChild(topimg);
        topimg.style.width = '200px';
        bottomimg.src = localStorage.getItem('bottomC');
        bottomcontainer.appendChild(bottomimg);
        bottomimg.style.width = '300px';
        faceimg.src = 'face.png';
        facecontainer.appendChild(faceimg);
        faceimg.style.width = '130px'
        
        loadoutfit3.value = 'Loaded!'
        loadoutfit3.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 167, 0)';
        setTimeout (function(){
        loadoutfit3.value = 'Load Outfit 3'
        loadoutfit3.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(119, 119, 223)';
        }, 2000);
    
    
    console.log('success');
    }
    if(localStorage.getItem('shoesC' || 'topC' || 'bottomC')== ''){
        error.innerHTML += '<li>No Outfit Saved</li>'
        setTimeout(function(){error.innerHTML = ''}, 2000)};
    }
```

Comment: You have multiple functions with the same name, that's not going to work. In general, when you find yourself copy-pasting whole sections of code, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: This: `localStorage.getItem('shoesB' || 'topB' || 'bottomB')!= ''` isn't going to work either; you have to get each item individually and compare each one of them to the empty string separately.